# extending a wordpress plugin - access to variables/methods from other plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to extend the plugin [Cleverness to do list](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cleverness-to-do-list/) by putting my own customizations in a separate plugin, however, I'm not able to access any methods/properties from the cleverness-todo-list plugin.

There is a display() function inside the original plugin that I want to customize. I want to show the "completed" todo items as well, which, if I was just to hack the original plugin all I would need to do is add these two lines of code in the display function in the cleverness-to-do-list-frontend.class.php:

```
$this->list .= '<h1>Completed Todos</h1>';
$this->loop_through_todos( 1, $category );
```

But I'm not sure how to access $this, $this->list, or $this->loop_through_todos()   from inside my own custom plugin without touching the original plugin.

I tried to just include the files where those methods/properties come from, and then call the function like I normally would, but it's not working and I'm not sure what to do.

```
function clever_travel_list()
{
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        //lines 710/711 of cleverness-to-do-list-frontend.class.php
        include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/cleverness-to-do-list/includes/cleverness-to-do-list.class.php';
        include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/cleverness-to-do-list/includes/cleverness-to-do-list-frontend.class.php';
        $this->list .= '<h1>Completed Todos</h1>';
        $this->loop_through_todos( 1, $category );
        die(ClevernessToDoList::$list);
    }

}
add_action('ctdl_list_items', clever_travel_list);
```

with the $this I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /Applications/AMPPS/www/wpplugin/wp-content/plugins/clever-extension/clever-extension.php on line 11
```

So how do I access properties/methods when I'm extending a plugin with another plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the "Cleverness to do list" plugin activated, you shouldn't need the `include`s.  While they *load* the code, they're not creating or initialising the associated objects (which is why it'd be easier to have the plugin activated if possible).

Looking at the code, `cleverness-to-do-list-frontend.class.php` is stored in a global variable `$CTDL_Frontend_Admin` once it's initialised, so something like this should work:

```
function clever_travel_list()
{
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        global $CTDL_Frontend_Admin;
        $CTDL_Frontend_Admin->list .= '<h1>Completed Todos</h1>';
        $CTDL_Frontend_Admin->loop_through_todos( 1, $category );
        die(ClevernessToDoList::$list);
    }
}
```

Though using a `die()` call seems wrong - was that just for debugging?